# How do I remove unnecessary characters from regex results?

Tags: python, regex

I have input as software and software versions as such (just examples):

- Oracle 1.1 Database
- Oracle 2.2
- Oracle 3.3 Platform
- Oracle DB 4.4
- Oracle 50.50

My desired output is:

- Oracle 1.1
- Oracle 2.2
- Oracle 3.3
- Oracle 4.4
- Oracle 50.50

I can successfully get 4 out of 5 of them with

```
re.compile('Oracle \d*.\d*')
```

The issue is the 'Oracle DB 4.4'. How do I get regex to ignore the 'DB' and just return the 'Oracle 4.4' but also still work for the rest of the inputs?

Comment: can you just do a `replace(' DB', '')` and then run the regex?

Comment: A regex **matches** strings and substrings, it does not change them. You can adjust it to match even if the `DB` is present, but to actually remove it from the string you will need to do a replace operation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 capturing groups where `DB`  is optional

```
(Oracle )(?:DB )?(\d+(?:\.\d+))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U7lTVW/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iqugLj)

If the decimal part is not optional:

```
(Oracle )(?:DB )?(\d+\.\d+)
```

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups.

```
result = re.sub(regex, r"\1 \2", test_str)
```